# How to apply a storyboard on a trigger selectively based on if the TargetProperty exists

Tags: wpf, binding, storyboard, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have a `DataTrigger` that animates `Background.Color` on a Grid Row. It works good when `Background` is of type [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) because that has a [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

But when that Grid Row is highlighted, the Background becomes [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) which [does not have a Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) property and my storyboard fails with an exception. How do I deal with that ?

Here is my Trigger

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Row.State}" Value="Finished">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(Color)" 
                                    To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Here is the exception that I get when row is highlighted.

> Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Background.(Color)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.

I used the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` like this

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

Apparently it looks for type by the name `SolidColorBrush`.

More information about Parenthesis is found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979945.aspx)

> In the multiple objects and subproperties form, you must use an owning object to disambiguate the initial property and place parentheses around this initial object.property combination. Thereafter, subproperties need only be named, not qualified with owning types, but those subproperties must exist on the preceding property's value type. A slightly more verbose form that qualifies subsequent subproperty owning types is also acceptable; for example, "(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)".